# QGIS c++ plugin get Vector layer attribute

Tags: c++, qt, qgis

I am using QT Creator to write a plugin for QGIS Desktop 2.8.3 (Nightly). My idea is to get the list of layer name in the current project, put them in a list and every time I click an item, the plugin will get the attribute table and put it in to a table widget.

I think I almost get all of them except after getting all the attribute, QGIS get dumped.

Here is my diagram of plugin:
mainapp ==load=> form1 ==load=> form2

As a plugin, mainmodule has a

```cpp
QgisInterface* mIface
```

which I pass from mainapp to form1 and eventually to form2 by a public void like this

```cpp
void form1::get_iface(QgisInterface* interface)
{
    mIface=interface;
}
```

Then every time I click an item in the list view, the plugin will get attribute by this:

```cpp
void form02::get_attrib_table(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    QString targetname=item->text();
    QStringList myString;
    int targetindex;
    for (int i=0;i<mIface->legendInterface()->layers().count();i++)
    {
        if (mIface->legendInterface()->layers().at(i)->name()==targetname)
        {
            targetindex=i;
            goto aab;
        }
    }
    aab:;

    QgsMapLayer* abc=mIface->legendInterface()->layers().at(targetindex);
    QgsVectorLayer* mypLayer = dynamic_cast<QgsVectorLayer*>(abc);
    //get attribute table format, ie. column headers
    ui->tableWidget->clear();
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(mypLayer->pendingFields().count());
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(mypLayer->pendingFeatureCount());
    for (int i=0;i<mypLayer->pendingFields().count();i++)
    {
          myString<<mypLayer->pendingFields().field(i).name();
    }
    ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(myString);


///get feature data
if (mypLayer->featureCount()>0)
{
    int fcount=mypLayer->featureCount();
    int hcount=mypLayer->pendingFields().count();

    for (int p=0;p<fcount;++p)
    {
        mypLayer->select(p);
        for (int i=0;i<hcount;i++)
        {
            QTableWidgetItem *item=new QTableWidgetItem(mypLayer->selectedFeatures().at(p).attribute(i).toString());
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(p,i,item);
        }
        mypLayer->deselect(p);
    }
    delete mypLayer;
    delete abc;
}
}
```

After all I was successful to get the needed data, but then QGIS crashed and created a minidump.
I am not sure if I do the right thing by passing and using mIface like that.

Also, in another plugin, **when there is no layer loaded**, I can load a layer from files and get the attribute with the same code.

There is so little material on QGIS c++ plugin and I am still new to this.